# Labview - How to merge scatter and surface 3d plots?

Tags: plot, 3d, labview

I have 2 sets of data for 3D plot. First is defined on scattered grid and consist of X-,Y-,Z-vector, the second is defined on structured grid, consist of X-,Y-,Z-matrix and is obtained by interpolation of the first.
How do I plot surface of the second and points of the first inside of one 3d plot?

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions on the web, such as:

http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/0ABACC8B023C15D3862572ED0070E4A6

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-4271

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-4585

You can go over and find the one which matches to your problem